# Riesz-Thorin theorem in finite-dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, interpolation-theory

In all formulation of Riesz-Thorin complex interpolation theorem I saw (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem)), it always involves function spaces like $L^p$. I would like to know if this theorem can be applied to linear operators on e.g. finite dimensional complex Hilbert space. I have seen this being used in several places, but they do not say why it works there.

As I am not very familiar with functional analysis, I would like to have some explicit arguments on how to pass from $L^p$ spaces, where the linear operators act on functions and then one evaluates the relevant $L^p$ norms, to complex Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^d$ where the norms involved in the theorem for the complex interpolation should be replaced by Schatten $p$-norms for linear operators (which in this case would be some finite-dimensional matrices). My guess is that this should not be hard but I don't know how much functional analysis is needed to do this.

Comment: Consider a subspace of $L^p$ generated by a finite set of $L^p$-functions. Then these are $L^p$ spaces as well, and by construction finite-dimensional hence isomorphic to $\mathbb C^d$. Since all norms on finite-dimensional spaces are equivalent, you may replace this with e.g. a Schatten norm. This is the only context I can make sense of your question.

Comment: Take the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and equip it with the counting measure $\mu$. Then $L^p(\mu)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}^n$, equipped with the usual $\ell^p$ norm.